How to move API connections from Resource Group A to Resource Group B in Azure using Python?
I'm trying to move all my API connections in Azure from Resource Group A to Resource Group B. RG B is newly created and currently empty.
I used this code:
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient

# Define your subscription ID and resource group names
subscription_id = "[REDACTED]"
tenant_id = "[REDACTED]"
client_id = "[REDACTED]"
client_secret = "[REDACTED]"

# Authenticate using Azure Identity
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

# Resource groups
resource_group_name_source = "azdnaeurgrgp1dev" #RG A
resource_group_name_target = "azmgmteurgrgpdev" #RG B

# Get all resources in the source resource group
resources = list(resource_client.resources.list_by_resource_group(resource_group_name_source, filter="resourceType eq 'Microsoft.Web/connections'"))

# Move each resource to the target resource group
for resource in resources:
    resource_id = resource.id
    name = resource.name  
    types = resource.type  
    managed_by = resource.managed_by 
    tags = resource.tags

    print(
    "Resource ID:", resource_id,
    "\nName:", name,
    "\nTypes:", types,
    "\nManaged By:", managed_by,
    "\nTags:", tags)

    # Check if properties is None and initialize it if necessary
    if resource.properties is None:
        resource.properties = {}
    
    # Update the resource group property to the target resource group
    resource.properties['resourceGroup'] = resource_group_name_target
    
    # Update the resource in the target resource group
    resource_client.resources.update(
        resource_group_name_target, 
        resource_id, 
        resource)

print("Resources moved successfully to", resource_group_name_target)

But it's not working the error I'm getting is:
AttributeError: 'ResourcesOperations' object has no attribute 'update'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2269390313065795> in <module>
     42 
     43     # Update the resource in the target resource group
---> 44     resource_client.resources.update(
     45         resource_group_name_target,
     46         resource_id,

AttributeError: 'ResourcesOperations' object has no attribute 'update'

I've also tried begin_create_or_update, and create_or_update_by_id still no luck on that. ChatGPT is just cycling on this 3 solustions.
